# How to start cmd batch loop in reversed order? (with the last directory)

Tags: loops, batch-file

my workdir looks like:

- C:\Workdir\Dir1
- C:\Workdir\Dir2
- C:\Workdir\Dir3

i am starting a batchfile with this loop:

```
for /D %%a in (*) do (
```

and then my actual command progresses each directory one after another.
but i need to start the progressing reversed. by starting with the last directory and then working upwards. starting with Dir3 and then Dir2 and then Dir1
how do i do that?

Comment: How about you try explaining what determines 'the last directory'

Comment: my question does not explain that? by last i meant the last according windows shell natural sort order

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should loop using "for /f" and then list all folders in the reverse order via the "dir" command.

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=*" %%G in ('dir /s /b /A:D /O:-N "%CD%"') do (
    echo %%G
)
```

Where:

- %CD% - is current directory - same if you call "in (*)" from the same directory
- /O:-N is reverse order by name
- https://ss64.com/nt/dir.html
- https://ss64.com/nt/for_d.html

Comment: thanks that helped :) i had to fix the further lines of my batchfile and replace following "%%a" to "%%~na" to not use the fullpath of %%a. but everything works now as intended

Comment: The `"%CD%"` is not needed: `dir` command list files in current directory by default. The `/s` switch, that list all files in the tree up to the last level, was not requested by the OP.

Answer (score 1):

As you have indicated a reversed Windows shell natural sort order you need to be made aware that numbers beyond single digit will cause you issues without additional work.

It would order like this:

```
Dir9
Dir8
Dir7
Dir6
Dir5
Dir4
Dir3
Dir2
Dir11
Dir10
Dir1
```

To fix this craziness, my suggested additional work utilises powershell:

```bat
@Echo Off
For /F "Delims=" %%A In ('
    PowerShell -C "Get-ChildItem | ?{ $_.PSIsContainer } | Select-Object -Expand Name | Sort-Object { [regex]::Replace($_, '\d+', { $args[0].Value.PadLeft(20) }) } -Descending"
') Do Echo %%A
Pause
```

Comment: Yes, good point; if natural Windows shell sort order is needed to be used (no Powershell is present), it is possible to workaround it by renaming folders to Dir01, Dir02, Dir03 etc.

Comment: Can you show me how your script will get all of the directory names, parse out the numeric sequences, 0 pad them, rename them then reverse order them?

Comment: @Compo i think he means that i may want to manually presort my folders to fit the sorting mechanism. i am already aware of the craziness, so i already sorted with leading zeros and such. but i still would like to understand how the powershell part works. what exactly does it do. thanks guys

Comment: In that case why not just rename the directories to DirZ, DirY, DirX. The Powershell part gets the directory names and sorts them in the manner you asked. Whilst many people here are happy to act as tutors I unfortunately am not. I hope that doesn't offend you, as that is not my intention.

Comment: no big deal. it does what it does. thats okey, peace