# Batch: For directories not working with delayed expansion

Tags: windows, batch-file, for-loop, cmd

I have a CI system that regularly publishes new files.
In a script, I want to take the latest version of several (separately published) files. The general file structure is the following: `C:\Path\to\publish\<token>\<flavor>\file`. There are 3 variable parts in this, per published file. (And all 3 can in some cases have wildcards in it)

The setup I currently have, makes use of delayed expansion to make this configurable:

```
set A_PATH=C:\Path\to\publish\*
set A_SUBDIR=<flavor>
set A_NAME=file_*.txt

call :searchFile A
goto :logicUsingA

:searchFile
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set SEARCH_PATH=%~1_PATH
set SEARCH_NAME=%~1_NAME
set SEARCH_SUBDIR=%~1_SUBDIR
FOR /D %%I IN ('DIR !%SEARCH_PATH%! /O:-D /B') do (
 echo I:%%I
 FOR %%J IN (!%SEARCH_SUBDIR%!) do (
  echo J:%%J
  FOR /F "delims=" %%K IN ('DIR %%I\%%J\!%SEARCH_NAME%! /A:-D /O:-D /B') do (
   echo K:%%K
   ENDLOCAL
   set "%~1=%%I\%%J\%%K"
   GOTO :EOF
  )
 )
) 2> nul
```

This system almost did what it needed to do, namely, based on a configuration pick some files and fill a variable with them.
Unfortunately, we discovered that something goes wrong with executing this script.

The `FOR /D %%I IN ('DIR !%SEARCH_PATH%! /O:-D /B')` should sort the directories with the newest first. However, the print below it, prints: (assume 001 was created before 002 ...)

```
I:'DIR
I:C:\Path\to\publish\001
I:C:\Path\to\publish\002
I:C:\Path\to\publish\003
```

This makes me suspect that the delayed expansion doesn't play nice with the for-loop, as this is the only noticeable difference with other solutions I find at stackoverflow, like https://stackoverflow.com/a/45104510/2466431

Would it be possible to instruct the for-loop to execute this dir-command iso treating it as a list of items?

**EDIT:** What the code is trying to achieve is a windows batch variant of the bash one-liner: `ls -t C/Path/to/publish/*/<flavor>/file_*.txt`

Comment: `FOR /D %%I IN ('DIR !%SEARCH_PATH%! /O:-D /B') do (` should actually read `for /F "delims=" %%I in ('dir "!%SEARCH_PATH%!" /A:D /O:-D /T:C /B') do (` (the `/T:C` option might be needed to sort against creation date)

Comment: `/F` uses it to search for files instead of directories, so that doesn't work.  `/T:C` might indeed make sense, however, both should be the same (usually)

Comment: ...and `FOR %%J IN (!%SEARCH_SUBDIR%!) do (` might require the `/D` option, or it might be replaced by `for /F "delims=" %%J in ('dir "%%I\!%SEARCH_SUBDIR%!" /A:D /B') do (`...

Comment: No, `for` *without* an option searches files; `for /F` reads and parses text line by line (type `for /?` and read the help); depending on the type of quotation of the part after `in`, the text comes from a file, a literal string or the output of a command, the latter of which is used here (command `dir`)...

Comment: @aschipfl For the middle loop, it's always fixed text, the only reason for the loop is to work around the delayed expansion

Comment: Well, `for` or `for /D` only search for files or directories if there is at least a wildcard after `in`, so `for %%I in (a b c) do echo %%I` always echos `a`, `b` and `c`, but `for %%I in (a*) do echo/%%I` returns files that begin with `a`...

Comment: @aschipfl I'll be fine with the second behavior if I can reverse it, as directory names are alphabetical (at the moment). It works better than the `/F` in combination with `dir` it seems, as that shows me the content of those dirs, instead of the actual directories that match the wildcard themselve

Comment: Yes, true, `dir /B /A:D` with a directory name given lists its contents; and `for /D` cannot sort by age; is the date/age of all levels `<token>\<flavor>\file` really relevant, or would it be sufficient to check the files (deepest level) only?

Comment: Checking at the deepest level only would be sufficient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The loop [`for /D`](https://ss64.com/nt/for_d.html)`%%I in ('dir !%SEARCH_PATH%! /O:-D /B') do ( ... )` is wrong as you must use [`for /F`](https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) to capture and parse the output of a command like [`dir`](https://ss64.com/nt/dir.html) in our situation. So you may either use `for /D %%I in ("!%SEARCH_PATH%!") do ( ... )` or `for /F "delims=" %%I in ('dir "!%SEARCH_PATH%!" /O:-D /B') do ( ... )` to be syntactically correct.

But neither will probably be useful for you, because:

- `for /D` does not access the file system unless [wildcards](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-wildcards.html) are present;
- `for /D` does not provide sort options (it returns directories as it gets them from the file system);
- `dir`, when a directory name is given, lists its contents rather than just returning its name;

Nevertheless, there is a way to work around the said problem with `dir`, namely appending `\` and trying to list the contents of the given directory; if wildcards are given, `dir` returns an error; if a dedicated directory name is given but it does not exist, `dir` returns an error too; [conditional execution](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) can be applied to make use of that behaviour:

```cmd
dir /B /A:D "%SomeDir%\" && (echo "%SomeDir%") || dir /B /A:D /O:-D /T:C "SomeDir%"
```

This provides the following results:

- if `%SomeDir%` points to a dedicated existing directory, the first `dir` command lists its contents, so it succeeds, hence the `echo` command is executed, returning the (quoted) variable contents, but the second `dir` command is skipped; (quotation of the `echo` string is done here in order to protect whitespaces or other special characters; the surrounding quotation marks `""` are no problem though as they can easily be removed later anyway;)
- if `%SomeDir%` points to a dedicated directory that cannot be found, the first `dir` command fails (error: `The system cannot find the file specified.`), hence the `echo` command is skipped, but the second `dir` command is executed, which also fails (error: `File Not Found`);
- if `%SomeDir%` contains a wildcard in the last path element, the first `dir` command fails (error: `The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.`), hence the `echo` command is skipped, but the second `dir` command is executed, which lists all matching directory names, sorted by creation date/time (newest first);

The listing returned by the first `dir` command as well as any error messages can be suppressed using [redirection](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html), so the remaining output is the one by `echo` or by the second `dir`:

```cmd
> nul 2>&1 dir /B /A:D "%SomeDir%\" && (echo "%SomeDir%") || 2> nul dir /B /A:D /O:-D /T:C "SomeDir%"
```

This can now be applied to your script:

```cmd
@echo off
set "A_PATH=C:\Path\to\publish\*"
set "A_SUBDIR=<flavor>"
set "A_NAME=file_*.txt"

call :searchFile A
echo A:%A%
rem goto :logicUsingA
goto :EOF

:searchFile
set "%~1="
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "SEARCH_PATH=%~1_PATH"
set "SEARCH_NAME=%~1_NAME"
set "SEARCH_SUBDIR=%~1_SUBDIR"
cd /D "!%SEARCH_PATH%!\.." || exit /B 1
for /F "delims=" %%I in ('
    ^> nul 2^>^&1 dir /B /A:D "!%SEARCH_PATH%!\" ^
        ^&^& ^(echo "!%SEARCH_PATH%!"^) ^
        ^|^| 2^> nul dir /B /A:D /O:-D /T:C "!%SEARCH_PATH%!"
') do (
    echo I:%%~nxI
    for /F "delims=" %%J in ('
        ^> nul 2^>^&1 dir /B /A:D "%%~nxI\!%SEARCH_SUBDIR%!\" ^
            ^&^& ^(echo "!%SEARCH_SUBDIR%!"^) ^
            ^|^| 2^> nul dir /B /A:D /O:-D /T:C "%%~nxI\!%SEARCH_SUBDIR%!"
    ') do (
        echo J:%%~J
        for /F "delims=" %%K in ('
            ^> nul 2^>^&1 dir /B /A:-D "%%~nxI\%%~J\!%SEARCH_NAME%!\" ^
                ^|^| 2^> nul dir /B /A:-D /O:-D /T:C "%%~nxI\%%~J\!%SEARCH_NAME%!"
        ') do (
            echo K:%%K
            endlocal
            set "%~1=%CD%\%%~nxI\%%~J\%%K"
            goto :EOF
        )
    )
)

goto :EOF
```

In the inner-most loop that enumerates files rather than directories, I applied the same technique, but I skipped the `echo` command as it should never be executed anyway; the only reason why I kept the two `dir` commands here is to handle the situation when you specify a certain file name (no wildcards) but there is actually a directory with that name (a single `dir` would then unintentionally return its contents).

There have also a few other things changed:

- the variable `%~1` is initially cleared (in the sub-routine `:searchFile`, just in case no file could be found at all);
- the quoted `set` syntax is consistently used (`set "VAR=Value"`);
- all paths are now quoted to avoit trouble with whitespaces or other special characters;
- the `dir` option `/T:C` is added to regard the creation date/time rather than the date/time of the last modification; just remove it if you want to regard the latter;
- [`cd /D`](https://ss64.com/nt/cd.html)`"!%SEARCH_PATH%!\.." ||`[`exit`](https://ss64.com/nt/exit.html)`/B 1` has been added to change to the parent directory, because the later used `dir /B` commands just return directory or file names but not full paths; that is also the reason why the [`~nx`-modifier](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html) is used in `%%~nxI`, so there is no more difference whether the value comes from `dir /B` or `echo`; the `exit /B 1` part makes sure to skip the remaining code in case the parent directory could not be found/accessed;
- [`~`-modifiers](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html) are used in `%%~J` to ensure unquoted directory names (remember that I put quotes in the `echo` command lines);
- `2> nul` has been removed (from the end of the body of the outer-most loop) to not suppress error messages in general;